# What is the meaning of plus in SASS

Tags: sass

I am reading the code of [bulma](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/sass/grid/columns.sass) and I am having trouble to understand the mening of "+" in front of a variable in SCSS

This is a code snippet using the "+" sign:

```
  +mobile
    &.is-narrow-mobile
      flex: none
    &.is-full-mobile
```

So what is it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's the shorthand for `@include` when using the indented syntax.

You can also replace `@mixin mixinName` with `=mixinName` when declaring new mixins.

Comment: `=mobile` is defined as `=mobile @media screen and ()` with extra line `@content`. Therefore `flex: none` can be injected there. I think we need this to understand `+`. Check an example here, https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/sass/utilities/mixins.sass

Comment: The official name for these shorthands is [Indented Mixin Syntax](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#indented-mixin-syntax)